# Internationalization in Oracle database

Tags: oracle10g

I am new to internationalization. We have a web application wherein the input of the data can be in 3 languages - english, French and Japanese.

There is going to be 1 central authority of the entire system which would like to retrieve and study whole data in English only.

How can we go about developing this kind of system? Do we need to maintain 3 different databases or can this be handled with a single database? Do we need to use some third party translator tool to achieve this?

This is urgent as we are stuck up with this issue.

Thanking u in anticipation 
Vaibhav

Comment: You don't mean that you want the database to translate the languages for you, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Technically in Oracle you can achieve this in one database.

The things you need to consider are a choice of character set, but this is much easier now with Unicode. You should read Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

*Far more complicated is how you are going to model your data, because you will need to know which data is in which language.*